# Including Bootstrap Modal only

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

i am trying to implement Bootstrap's dropdown Modal as shown in Bootstrap Documentation .if i include bootstrap.min.css it interefere the existing classes and changes the look and feel of page .i have to implement only Modal dont want to include other classes.any guidelines ??

Answer (score 3):

Use the Customize and download tool to get finer-grained control, kind of like a "build".  Just select those things applicable to the modal stuff:

EDIT (for v3): http://getbootstrap.com/customize/
http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html#components

Even if you end up needing to tweak further to make it work, this will be an easier place from which to start than poking around that entire minimized file.

Comment: The URL above is for Bootstrap v2.3.2. Most up-to-date URL (v3.2.0) is http://getbootstrap.com/customize/